# Como asegurar la persistencia en memoria de varios Spinner

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-spinner, baseadapter

tengo varios spinner que se renderizan por medio de un base adapter (24 spinners):

https://github.com/felipedelosh/LifeRegisterAPP/blob/main/app/src/main/java/Adapters/TimeDistributionAdapter.java

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.itemtimeinversion, null);
        }

        TextView listViewTimeInversionHourItem = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewTimeInversionHourItem);
        //Put hour
        String hour = getItemX(position).getHour();
        if (hour.length() == 3){
            listViewTimeInversionHourItem.setText(hour+"   >>");
        }else {
            listViewTimeInversionHourItem.setText(hour+" >>");
        }
        //Put Spinner options
        Spinner listViewTimeInversionSpinnerActivity = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewTimeInversionSpinnerActivity);
        ArrayAdapter<String> sprAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerValues);
        listViewTimeInversionSpinnerActivity.setAdapter(sprAdapter);
        getItemX(position).setSpinner(listViewTimeInversionSpinnerActivity);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Todos los spiners se muestran correctamente y funcionan correctamente el problema:

Solo existen en memoria los spinners que se muestran en la pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de bajar a ver las otras opciones los spiners superiores se borran... y no guarda los datos... Que puedo hacer?

Comment: ¿Esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21872631/11539923) te es útil?